# Trigger Stop sharing screen button in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

Once we start screen sharing on chrome browser we get screen sharing toolbar at the bottom of the screen with "Stop sharing" blue button on it.

[image]

The problem which I'm facing is, when a user starts multiple screen share with the same source, lets say "window". Every time we get a different `chromeMediaSourceId`.

If we programmatically try to stop any one of the screen share with the use of following code:

```
webRtcPeer.peerConnection.getLocalStreams()[0].getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

all the screen share instance with the same source stop immediately.

But if try to stop the screen share using the blue "Stop sharing" button this behavior is not observed.

Comment: How are you initiating the screen sharing?

Comment: By sending a message to `port.onMessage` which is a listiner in the extension code

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this usually means that you need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebRTC, maybe there is a method to stop sharing selectively, but as for the button, it looks like a part of Chrome's own UI, meaning you won't be able press it programmatically.

Comment: @wOxxOm in webRtc internally the stream is disposed which is causing the shared stream to end. whereas when click on the blue "Stop sharing" button is not stopping the shared stream and ending the screen share as expected